# How to enable Arensito Keyboard Layout on Windows

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, autohotkey

I am experiencing negative effects of RSI and am evaluating alternative keyboard layouts. The [`Arensito Keyboard Layout`](http://www.pvv.org/~hakonhal/main.cgi/keyboard) comes up frequently.

How can I use this layout on Windows?

[image]

Unfortunately, the homepage only provides for Linux `xkb`.

I have tried using [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339).  It doesn't seem able to map `AltGr` to `Space`.

Similarly with AutoHotKey; I can't make `Space` into `AltGr`.

If a layout or script doesn't already exist, how can I map the modifier keys like `AltGr` using AutoHotKey?